# Dynamic tabs + viewpager to show list in recyclerview

Tags: android

{"Response":{"ResponseCode":200,"ResponseText":"Success"},"Detail":[{"CategoryId":1,"CategoryName":"NonVegPizza","CategoryImage":null,"Types":[{"Name":"Pizza1","Items":[{"ItemId":1,"Name":"small","ImageURL":"imgurl","Description":"Smallpizzadescription","Amount":100},{"ItemId":2,"Name":"medium","ImageURL":"imgurl2","Description":"Medpizzadescription","Amount":200}],"ingredients":[{"IngredientId":1,"Name":"ing1","ImageURL":"ingurl1","Description":"description","Amount":20},{"IngredientId":2,"Name":"ing2","ImageURL":"ingurl2","Description":"description2","Amount":30}]},{"Name":"Pizza2","Items":[],"ingredients":[{"IngredientId":1,"Name":"ing1","ImageURL":"ingurl1","Description":"description","Amount":20},{"IngredientId":2,"Name":"ing2","ImageURL":"ingurl2","Description":"description2","Amount":30},{"IngredientId":3,"Name":"ing3","ImageURL":"ingurl3","Description":"description3","Amount":45},{"IngredientId":4,"Name":"ing4","ImageURL":"ingurl4","Description":"description4","Amount":55}]}]},{"CategoryId":2,"CategoryName":"Pizza","CategoryImage":null,"Types":[]},{"CategoryId":3,"CategoryName":"VegPizza","CategoryImage":null,"Types":[]}]}

Below providing code:-
for(i=0;i

want to show categoryName in tabs and under it want to show its detail in list format.

Comment: Show the code what you have tried till now.

Comment: Don't add code in comment section. Update your question by adding the whole code..And remove this code from comments

Comment: I posted it in 3 sections where I'm able to create dynamic tabs but no idea how to add list below every tab .

Comment: sir, I'm too new on stack over flow .so no idea how to edit my question

Comment: You can see three options as share, edit & flag under your question on left side under the android tag. Plz use them

Comment: Still can't see the code in question ??

Comment: i'm adding but not visible

Comment: plz check i have shared.